# Condensation inside packed, refrigerated food

Tags: food-safety, refrigerator

I've got a bit of a problem with my... refrigerator? I'm not sure.

Basically, after a single night in the fridge packed food develops severe condensation on the inside on the top-lid.

I wouldn't find this THAT strange if it happened only to packages that were opened... but this also happens to food I haven't open yet as well! Also I don't recall such a problem with my family home fridge.

I think it's a case of incorrectly set temperature, but I don't know if the current setting is too high or too low (and all I've got to work with is a single knob with relatively meaningless numbers 0-7). That said, the temperature inside the fridge seems fine (I haven't actually measured it, but it feels cool, and things like butter are as hard as I'd expect them to be). Or, perhaps, it's something else entirely, like some other fault with the fridge.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is something wrong with your refrigerator, and you need to get it fixed.

Most likely, the temperature inside is rising into the danger zone (>40F), and subsequently falling as the fridge cools. This change in temperature causes the condensation.

In a [discussion on ChowHound](http://www.chowhound.com/post/containers-fridge-condensation-bad-615010?page=2), there were many potential issues discussed that could be causing your problem. Take a look at my list below and determine how comfortable you are inspecting each issue. If you find one of the problems and can fix it, great.

Most likely, you need to call the manufacturer if the fridge is under warranty, or call an appliance repair specialist to come take a look. Don't wait too long, it's quite possible some of your food is spoiled because of the issue.

Possible problems causing the issue:

- bad thermometer inside fridge
- door isn't sealing tightly enough
- freezer needs to be defrosted
- drain is clogged
- could be something else entirely

Comment: An overly enthusiastic defrost cycle can do things like this (especially in the fridge is part of a fridge freezer). That in turn can be caused by too much frost buildup or a blocked drain hole

Comment: I'm guessing simply setting the fridge to be cooler (I'm assuming a larger number means more cooling) probably wont solve the issue?

Comment: @Shaamaan It won't solve the problem permanently, and in fact may even make it worse by working the fridge harder. I would second Caleb's advice to get the fridge checked by an appliance specialist.